# Difference between 那 vs 呢 and when to use it

Tags: usage, difference

What is the difference between 那 vs 呢 and where should I use it?

Comment: These two characters are not even similarly close to one another. Did you perhaps mean 哪 and 呢? 哪 can sometimes be used as a sort of modal particle at the end of sentences in a somewhat similar way to 呢. But again they're essentially quite different. Or did you maybe me whats the difference in pronunciation between `na` and `ne`?

Comment: Can you provide situations where these two words can be somewhat interchangeable? It is so hard to imagine a situation where you might mess up with these two words.

Answer (score 1):

哪:

1.
Question words. Ex:  Where is he?  *他在哪兒？* , How do I know?、*我哪兒知道？*

2.
After the end of nasal rhyme. Same to *啊* . Ex: *天哪！*  (天啊!)

3.
[哪吒](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%93%AA%E5%90%92):A fairy in a Buddhist story. In the novel, there is a story that the broken bones return to the parents and appear as the parents. Or called *哪吒三太子*.

呢:

1.Whispering. Metaphor the euphemistic voice. Ex: *細語呢喃*

2.Auxiliary word.

> 2.1 Show the problem. Ex: What should I do? *我該怎麼辦呢?*
>
> 2.2 Show confirm. Ex: It's still early! *時間還早得很呢！*
>
> 2.3 The tone of the expression stops. Ex: Although your travel plan is very attractive, but! I don't want to go at all. *雖然你的計畫很吸引人，可是呢！我一點都不想去。*

那:

1.Demonstrative pronouns. Ex: *那天*、*那本書*

2.Tone words that express acceptance and transition. Ex: If you have something to do, then I will find someone to go. *如果你有事要忙，那我就找別人去*